# Нужно ли использовать return (*аргумент) в функции с указателем, если и без него нормально работает ?

Tags: c

Есть ли смысл прописывать `return(*x);` в функции increaser , ибо без `return(*x);` программа всёравно выдаёт нужный результат (**семёрку**) ?

```
int increaser(int* x) //используем указатель
{

 (*x)++;
 //return (*x);

};

int main() // точка входа
{

int x = 6;
increaser(&x); // изменится ли х ?
printf("%d\n", x);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: нет, не нужно: `void increaser(int* x) { ...`. Чем меньше строчек кода Вы напишете, тем меньше сделаете в них ошибок. *Народная мудрость*

Comment: Зависит от того, *что на самом деле вы хотите* от этой функции (т.е. как  собираетесь ее *использовать*). Опишите это словами (если не получится, добавьте пару примеров).

Comment: Нормальные компиляторы на такое ругаются. И в вашем случае можно было объявить функцию как `void increaser(int *x);`

Comment: Очень, очень странный вопрос. Нужно ли при лечении использовать таблетки или уколы? Вопрос в том, что вы лечите и как. Нет и не может быть общего правила - использовать или не использовать - без привязки к *конкретной* функции и условиям ее применения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо, зачем вам возвращать значение? Вы ведь инкрементируете переменную по указателю и возврат данных указателя тут неуместен и не нужен. Оно и так изменит значение. Это бы имело смысл если бы вы передавали данные не по ссылке (указателю), а по значению. Тогда в переменную которую вы передали в параметры функции, вам надо было указывать данные которое вернула бы функция. Но так теряется сам смысл передачи не по ссылке и чем данные больше, тем более трудоемкая это будет задача для компилятора.

Но есть одно НО, ваша функция задекларинована на возврат `int` данных, в таком случае возврат **обязательный**.

Comment: Нужно. Ибо задекларировано, что функция возвращает `int`

Comment: Да, не обратил на это внимание. Благодарю.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov То, что функция объявлена с возвращаемым значением, не значит, что она должна действительно его возвращать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Ну да. Наличие протокола совсем не означает, что его нужно придерживаться. Мы сделаем как нам удобно, а проблемы вызывающей стороны нас не беспокоят